# Does there any O(1) Solution exist for this Problem?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, optimization

We have been given an array of size N `1 <= N <= 1e5`, with `Ai` positive integers, such that

`1 <= Ai <= 1e9`.

we will be given Q queries. `1 <= Q <= 1e5` 
Every time in a query there will be two space separated integers `b c` , `1 <= b,c <= N`

For every query we need to find that `Is moving from index b of array to index c of array possible ?`, and if it is then we have find a special sum, which i have explained below.

We can't just move in array simply from `i to i+1` index, there is a restriction. If we want to move from `i to j` then A[j] should be strictly greater than A[i], i.e `A[j] > A[i]`. 
Note here one thing that : `While moving we have to take the just next greater element than the current.`

The `sum` what we need to find is sum of elements that came in the path taken to reach destination.

**For Example** 
array : `3 2 5 4 6 6 7`
query : `1 7`
So, according to query we need to move from 1st element to last element if possible.

As, we can see we can take `3 --> 5 --> 6 --> 7` path to reach the destination and sum is `3+5+6+7 = 21`

But if last element in array was `2`
array : `3 2 5 4 6 6 2`
query : `1 7`
For this query we cant reach to destination as after `6` the destination element `2` is smaller than it. So for this query `NO answer exist`.

**My approach** 
I know i can find the answer in `O(n)`, by traversing the array simply from `A(b) to A(c)` and finding out that if answer exit or not as well as `sum`. 
But the Problem is that There are a lot of queries so if i use `O(n)` solution the Time Complexity will be `O(QN)`. 
Time limit is only `1 sec`, So i need to find a constant time `O(c)`solution for this.

One Thing more The becomes even tougher when Queries of second type appear. 
Query type 2: In this query we need to update the value at an index with a given `K`.
query : `b k` , then `A[b] = K`.

Can anyone help me on this ??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of your own attempt to solve this problem, together with a description of the problems you have with it.

Comment: Oh and note that big-O notation is about *complexity*, not absolute times or anything else. For time-complexity, the `1` in `O(1)` means that the complexity is *constant time*, which doesn't have to mean it takes exactly one second.

Comment: I am sorry, i am new to programming. I have edited the answer and removed c++14 tag.

Comment: Couldn't we have more than one possible sum? Which sum are we supposed to return? For example, given [1, 5, 4, 8], we can get from 1 to 8 either with 4 or with 5 (but not both).

Comment: We will go from 1 to 5 then to 8 , we cant fo from 1 to 4 as 5 occurs before 4 and is greater thann 1.  We have to move and have to take the next greater element. So if moving from 1 to 8 i will take 1 then the just next greater element is 5. So i will take 5 and then just next greater is 8 so 8 will be taken .

Answer (score 1):

The question is asking for N queries, the solution is most probably to do a pre-process to compute the possibilities and then query each of them in O(1) time.

Comment: Yes, You are correct But how can i pre-process it. Thats what i am not able to think.?? Please share if you know any approach.

Comment: I would think along the lines of all pairs shortest path as a preprocess https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem#All-pairs_shortest_paths.

Comment: Can you explain how to pre-process possibilities with any example, or with same example mention in question ??

Comment: Implementing Floyd warshall will result in a distance matrix with the shortest path of each two pairs, the query would be if d[i][j] is infinity then it is not reachable otherwise you check if the path is less than the given query. I am not sure if there a faster dynamic programming approach.

Comment: This is also called Transitive_closure https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure

Comment: That was really helpful, but still i  have a problem. I need to create a 2D matrix D[n][n], in which n can go as large as `200000`. So if i create this matrix, its definitely gonna give me TLE in C++14, as time limit for this is only 1 sec.

Comment: I mean the question is asking for any query, so that's n*n, I am not sure if this can be optimized more (it probably can) but I would try this first.